# Context.getContentResolver().query() gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-cursor

I am working on a music project where I am using a song's id to find out its title. This is the function that I use to do so. It is in MetadataFinder class.

```
public static String getSongFromID(long id, Context context) {
        Uri mediaContentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"" + id}; //This is the id you are looking for

        Cursor mediaCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(mediaContentUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if (mediaCursor.getCount() >= 0) {
            mediaCursor.moveToPosition(0);
            String title = mediaCursor.getString(mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            return title;
            //Do something with the data
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This has worked very well so far. But now when I am calling this method from another portion of code it gives null pointer exception.

I have two fragments from where I send broadcast to the main activity. The main activity broadcast receiver calls a function in a service, lets call it MainService. This method in the service calls the above method getSongFromID. I am calling this method from both the fragments. For the same values of 'id' and context 'MainService.this', I get exception in one case while the other works fine.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getCount()' on a null object reference
at com.app.utils.MetadataFinder.getSongFromID(CommonUtils.java:331)
at com.app.services.MainService.playSong(MainService.java:189)
at com.app.activity.MainActivity.initPanelBottom(MainActivity.java:235)
at com.app.activity.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:155)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:866)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I can't understand what the reason behind this might be as I see no difference in any of the involved parameters. Can someone please help me !!

```
String title = MetadataFinder.getSongFromID(i, MainService.this);
```

This is how I am calling getSongFromId() function. It is a static function in MetadataFinder class.

Comment: `mediaCursor` is `null`. check that before `mediaCursor.getCount()`

Comment: The `query(...)` method can return `null`.

Comment: @Titus yes it can but why is it returning null in one case and not the other, if the parameters are exactly the same?

Comment: @RohitArya yes it is null, and that is the problem I am facing. Why is it null in one case and not the other when other parameters are same? The only variable in the case is context and id, which are same for calls from both fragments. In that case why one of the call results in null and other works fine?

Comment: Okay, post the code of how are you using this method `etSongFromID(long id, Context context)` from both places.

Comment: @RohitArya I have added the cod, please have a look at it.

Comment: Maybe your database doesn't allow multi-reading, and since you didn't close the cursor on the first one, the second attempt will return `Cursor` as `null`. Try to close the cursor in the function `getSongFromID`

Comment: Your context is probably wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix my issue, thanks to [Nguyen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4565805/nguyen-quang-anh) suggestion. I closed my cursors at all places where I had forgot to do so and finally things worked right.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you initialize your Helper Class's object in Content Provider's class's onCreate() method.

For example:

[image]